# How to escape the hash character (#) in the M4 preprocessor?

Tags: escaping, m4

How can I escape the hash character (#) in M4?

My M4 macro is this:

```
define(`lnk',<a target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a>)dnl
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
lnk(http://www.example.com)
```

To produce this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
```

My problem is when I try to use it like this:

```
lnk(http://www.example.com#anchor)
```

Then I get this error:

```
ERROR: end of file in argument list
```

And that's because of the hash character (#). How can I fix this? Do I have to escape the hash character in M4?

I'm using M4 for Windows (using Win 10 x64), downloaded from the gnuwin32 project

Answer (score 1):

You should quoting your strings because of unwanted expansions. In your case:

```
lnk(`http://www.example.com#anchor')
```

But you can disable or redefine the comment characters. Default is `#` at begin and newline at the end. This macro is `changecom` (see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html)).

```
changecom()dnl
define(`lnk',<a target="_blank" href="$1">$1</a>)dnl
lnk(http://www.example.com#anchor)
```